# como usar JList y Un ArrayList java

Tags: java, arraylist, polimorfismo

estoy intentando crear un listado de vehículos hice 4 clases la clase padre y las hijas que son terrestres aéreas y marítimas.

lo que hago es algo así

```
public static ArrayList<Transportation> transportations = new ArrayList<Transportation>();
```

y le agrego datos así

```
Transportation overland = new Overland("1", "451fsfd4", "p0245", "serie 5", "2016", "4", "4 persons", 165000.00, 5, "Honda civic", 1);

Transportation overland1 = new Overland("2", "4444531s4", "oq45", "prueba", "2011", "4", "4 persons", 565000.00, 7, "bugati", 1);

Transportation Aerial = new Aerial("3", 2, 3, 2, 1000000.00, "aeroplano", 2, 4); 

Transportation Maritimo = new Maritimos("4", "serie 4", "BAVARIA", "30 personas", 3000000.00, "yate prueba", "lancha", 3, 1); 

transportations.add(overland); transportations.add(overland1); 

transportations.add(Aerial); transportations.add(Maritimo);
```

intento insertarlos en un JList algo así

```
JList list= new JList();

list.setModel(transportations);
```

también probé mandarselo

```
for (Transportation trasporte : trasportstions) {
  post.setModel(transporte);
}
```

agradeceria mucho la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el constructor de `JList -> JList(Object[])` sólo debes de hacer esto:

```
JList list = new JList(transportations.toArray());
```

Comment: gracias amigo me ayudo tu respuesta saludos.